# Multiple auth guards in Lumen framework

Tags: laravel, authentication, lumen, lumen-5.2

Please, can anybody explain how to implement multiple authentication guards in Lumen framework? Currently, I have two authenticatable models: **Users** and **Clients**. I'm using a custom implementation of JWT. A User has `client_id` and `user_id` fields in their token payload. While a Client only has `client_id`. Based on this I need to determine who came to me: client, user or guest (without a token).

**auth.php**

```
'guards' => [
    'client' => [
        'driver' => 'token',
        'provider' => 'clients',
    ],
    'user' => [
        'driver' => 'token',
        'provider' => 'users',
    ],
],

'providers' => [
    'clients' => [
        'driver' => 'eloquent',
        'model' => App\Client::class,
    ],
    'users' => [
        'driver' => 'eloquent',
        'model' => App\User::class,
    ],
],
```

**AuthServiceProvider.php**

```
public function boot()
{
    $this->app['auth']->viaRequest('token', function ($request) {
        $access_token = HelperClass::getTokenFromHeader($request->headers->get('Authorization'));

        if ($access_token) {
            $tokendata = JWT::decode($access_token, getenv('TOKEN_SECRET'), array('HS256'));

            if ($tokendata->user_id) {
                return User::find($tokendata->user_id);
            }

            return Client::find($tokendata->client_id);
        }
    });
}
```

**routes.php**

```
$app->get('/api/{item_id:\d+}', ['middleware' => 'auth:user', 'uses' => 'App\Http\Controllers\ItemController@get']);
```

I want to allow only Users to access this route, but Clients successfully pass this middleware too: `Auth::check()` returns `true` and `Auth::user()` returns an instance of App\Client

Another situation: what if for some routes I want to allow both: clients **and** users. For another routes - guests, clients and users.

Comment: did you able to solve it?